# Could not find or access a file that is in the local directory

Tags: ansible, ansible-template

I have got an error in my project, when I am trying to copy from local directory to remote one

error message:

```
fatal: [xxx]: FAILED! => {
"changed": false, "msg": "could not find 
src=/Users/xxx/Desktop/Docker/The_Task/./roles/docker_registry/templates,
Could not find or access 
'/Users/xxx/Desktop/Docker/The_Task/./roles/docker_registry/templates' 
on the Ansible Controller.\n
If you are using a module and expect the file to exist on the remote, see the remote_src option"
}
```

playbook.yml

```
- name: Copying required files
  template:
    src: ./roles/docker_registry/templates
    dest: /tmp/docker_registry
```

if i do:

```
cd /Users/xxx/Desktop/Docker/The_Task/./roles/docker_registry/templates
```

it changes directory to the directory i want to ... the error seems to be from ansible side. ( it doesnt work with absolute path eighter )

if I use the default copy module, then it works pretty much fine

```
- name: copy files [local -> remote]
  copy:
    src: ./roles/docker_registry/templates
    dest: /tmp/docker_registry
```

any idea what should i do to make it work ? [ its copying from LOCAL -> REMOTE ]

---

### But still i can not copy the whole dir into the remote machine

Comment: 50% closed ( solved only for files, not directories )

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Solution only for "Files"**

---

okay, I am gonna keep this, just in case someone will stumble upon the same problem as I did ... the thing i messed up is that `src:` is looking into the roles `templates` files ... the error has told me that its accessing the `full path` which is not true ... its accessing only a `templates` file and it continues from there ...

fixed code:

```
- name: Copying required files
  template:
    src: docker-compose.yml
    dest: /tmp/docker_registry
```